# Cordova doesn't detect JDK installation

Tags: cordova, java-deployment-toolkit

I am using windows.
When I type in the cmd `cordova requirements` I get the following message:

```
Java JDK: not installed
```

I have tried the following:

-I have installed the JDK both version 8 and 16

-I have a JAVA_HOME variable pointing to the path of jdk 8 (and I tried 16 as well, doesn't work)

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: did you reopen the cmd window after setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable? It doesn't pick changes unless you close and reopen.

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried reinstalling cordova, the jdk, and restarting my pc

Comment: how does it look like?

Comment: I edited the question to include a screenshot

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `JAVA_HOME` variable

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291

Comment: I put this value both in the user variable and system variable, either way it doesn't work

Comment: did you also add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the Path system variable?

Comment: I did, I added it like this, not with the variable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin

Comment: Could you run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in your console? What it shows? What version of cordova do you have (`cordova --version`)? Can you create the default app from the ground with the following commands and retest the requirements (`cordova create blah` `cd blah` `cordova platform add android` `cordova requirments`)?

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME% - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\

Comment: cordova --version - 10.0.0

Comment: Tried doing the default app, it works. What is the problem for my non default app?